# LogRepository Not Saving Logging with Custom Annotation and Saving Via JPARepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, aspectj

I am trying to Log All methods from Controller with Custom Annotation and Save to Database via JPARepository

When I run this nothing gets written to the "logs" Table
I am new to stack and also Java Spring so please spare blunders and correct as needed.

```java
package com.davidoladeji.epx.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {
    String page();
    String action();
    String description();
}
```

```java
   package com.davidoladeji.epx.controller;



import com.davidoladeji.epx.annotation.Loggable;
import com.davidoladeji.epx.model.*;
import com.davidoladeji.epx.repository.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


@Controller
@SessionAttributes("airplane")
public class AirplaneController {




    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    AirplaneRepository airplaneRepository;

    @Autowired
    QualificationRepository qualificationRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    LogRepository logRepository;


    @ModelAttribute("airplane")
    public Airplane createModel() {
        return new Airplane();
    }

    @Loggable(page="Airplane", action ="Changed Page to All Airplanes", description = "Entered List of all Airplanes Page")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allairplanes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allJobs(ModelAndView modelx) {

        List<Airplane> airplanes = airplaneRepository.findAll();
        modelx.addObject("airplanex", airplanes);
        modelx.addObject("title", "AirX System: All Airplanes");
        modelx.setViewName("allairplanes");




        //Get List of All Managers  for Statistics
        List<User> managers = userRepository.findByUserRole_Rolename("ROLE_ADMIN");
        modelx.addObject("managerx", managers);

        //Get List of All Engineers  for Statistics
        List<User> engineers = userRepository.findByUserRole_Rolename("ROLE_USER");
        modelx.addObject("engineerx", engineers);

        //Get List of All Jobs  for Statistics
        List<Job> alljobs = jobRepository.findAll();
        modelx.addObject("jobx", alljobs);

        //Personalisation
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        //get user role to determine stuff to display like username and dashboard title
        Role usersrole = new Role();

        boolean isAdminhasRolen = usersrole.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN");

        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        if (isAdminhasRolen) {
            modelx.addObject("title", "AirX System: Administrator Dashboard");
            modelx.addObject("userrolelabel", "Administrator");

        } else {

            modelx.addObject("title", "AirX System: Engineer Dashboard");
            modelx.addObject("userrolelabel", "Engineer");
        }

        modelx.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
        //General Stuff for Display ends

        return modelx;
    }




    @Loggable(page="Airplane", action ="Changed Page to New Airplane", description = "Entered New Airplanes Page")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newairplane", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newAirplane(Locale locale, ModelAndView modelx) {


        List<Airplane> airplanes = airplaneRepository.findAll();
        modelx.addObject("airplanex", airplanes);



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Get List of All Managers  for Statistics
        List<User> managers = userRepository.findByUserRole_Rolename("ROLE_ADMIN");
        modelx.addObject("managerx", managers);

        //Get List of All Engineers  for Statistics
        List<User> engineers = userRepository.findByUserRole_Rolename("ROLE_USER");
        modelx.addObject("engineerx", engineers);

        //Get List of All Jobs  for Statistics
        List<Job> alljobs = jobRepository.findAll();
        modelx.addObject("jobx", alljobs);

        //Personalisation
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        //get user role to determine stuff to display like username and dashboard title
        Role usersrole = new Role();

        boolean isAdminhasRolen = usersrole.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN");

        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        if (isAdminhasRolen) {
            modelx.addObject("title", "AirX System: Administrator Dashboard");
            modelx.addObject("userrolelabel", "Administrator");

        } else {

            modelx.addObject("title", "AirX System: Engineer Dashboard");
            modelx.addObject("userrolelabel", "Engineer");
        }

        modelx.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
        //General Stuff for Display ends


        modelx.setViewName("newairplane");
        return modelx;

    }

    @Loggable(page="Airplane", action ="Added Airplane", description = "Clicked on add airplane button")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addairplane", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public String addAirplane(@Valid Airplane airplane, BindingResult result) {


       if (result.hasErrors()) {

            return "redirect:/newairplane";
        } else {
           airplaneRepository.save(airplane);
            return "redirect:/allairplanes";
        }
        //  return "redirect:/";
    }

    @Loggable(page="Airplane", action ="Delete Airplane", description = "Clicked on Delete Airplanes Button")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/airplane/{airplane}",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public String deleteAirplane(@PathVariable("airplane") Long airplaneId, ModelAndView modelx) {


        airplaneRepository.delete(airplaneRepository.findOne(airplaneId));

        return "redirect:/allairplanes";

    }

    @Loggable(page="Airplane", action ="Changed Page to Single-Edit Airplane", description = "Entered Edit Airplanes Page")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/airplane/{airplane}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editAirplane(Locale locale, ModelAndView modelx) {


        modelx.setViewName("editairplane");
        return modelx;

    }

}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggableAdvice {
    @Autowired
    private LoggableService loggableService;

    @Before("execution(public String com.davidoladeji.epx.controller.*Controller.*(..)) && @annotation(logAnnotation) ")
    public void myBeforeLogger(Loggable logAnnotation) {
        loggableService.saveLog(logAnnotation.page(), logAnnotation.action(), logAnnotation.description());}
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "logs")
public class MyLog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    private String action;
    private String description;
    private String page;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String username;
    private String role;

    public MyLog() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.davidoladeji.epx.service;

import com.davidoladeji.epx.log.MyLog;
import com.davidoladeji.epx.repository.LogRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

@Service
public class LoggableService{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggableService.class);

    Locale locale = new Locale(Locale.UK.toString());
    @Autowired
    LogRepository logRepository;
    String username, userrole, currentdate, currenttime, datetime;

    /**
     * Log the current page and store details to a Log Instance and Save Via Repository to DB the logger checks*/
    public void saveLog(String page, String action, String description) {
        String username = getCurrentUsername();
        String date = getCurrentDate();
        String time = getCurrentTime();
        String userrole = getCurrentUserRole();

        MyLog myLog = new MyLog();
        myLog.setUsername(username);
        myLog.setAction(action);
        myLog.setDate(date);
        myLog.setTime(time);
        myLog.setDescription(description);
        myLog.setPage(page);
        myLog.setRole(userrole);

        logRepository.save(myLog);

        logger.info("CUSTOM LOG: {} - {}", username +"\n"+ page +"\n"+ action +"\n"+ description);
    }

    private String getCurrentUsername() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        username = userDetail.getUsername();
        return username;
    }

    private String getCurrentUserRole() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        userrole = userDetail.getAuthorities().toString();
        return userrole;
    }

    public String getCurrentDate() {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        currentdate = dateFormat.format(date);
        return currentdate;
    }

    public String getCurrentTime() {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        currenttime = dateFormat.format(date);
        return currenttime;
    }

    public String getCurrentDateTime() {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
        datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
        return datetime;
    }
}
```

I left the namespaces out (hope not a problem).Using Spring 3.25 though and IntelliJ (if that matters)

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties"/>


<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!--I need this for all packages to be scanned -->
<!-- check for duplicates: DONE -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.davidoladeji.epx">
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj"
                            expression="com.davidoladeji.epx.log.LoggableAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<!-- Imports logging configuration -->
<import resource="tracers-context.xml"/>

<!-- Imports datasource configuration -->
<import resource="spring-data.xml"/>

<bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties"/>


<!--<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"></bean>-->
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.davidoladeji.epx"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="resources/assets/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="resources/assets/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="resources/assets/js/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="resources/assets/fonts/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="resources/assets/img/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/prettify/**" location="resources/assets/prettify/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/ajax/**" location="resources/assets/ajax/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.davidoladeji.epx.log.LoggableAdvice"/>
<bean class="com.davidoladeji.epx.service.LoggableService"/>-->

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

```
Spring-data.xml
<beans>

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.davidoladeji.epx.repository"/>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->
    <bean id="jpaDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
          p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
          p:acquireIncrement="5"
          p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
          p:maxPoolSize="100"
          p:maxStatements="50"
          p:minPoolSize="10"/>


    <!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
          p:persistenceUnitName="hibernatePersistenceUnit"
          p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource"
          p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor"/>

    <!-- Specify ORM vendor -->
    <bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          p:showSql="false"/>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

</beans>

web.xml


    <web-app>

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<!--
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
        <param-value>en</param-value>
    </context-param>-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

AOP config is here

tracer-context.xml

```
    <beans>

    <bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="com.davidoladeji.epx.model.itools.Tracer"
          p:enterMessage="Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])"
          p:exitMessage="Leaving $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- e.g. getUserRoles in LoginService-->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


      <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
                      expression="execution(* com.davidoladeji.epx.service.*Service.*(..))"/>

        <!--Where should the advice be applied all files ending with Service-->
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut"/>
    </aop:config>


</beans>
```

Comment: I have reformatted your source code. It is Java, not Javascript, and you cannot run it in the browser. As for your problem, the crucial part of the code is missing: The controller class and package name. You omitted it and just posted a single method. This way I cannot verify if your pointcut should match or not. So please edit the question and provide more details. Because it could also be a configuration problem, please also provide Spring and AOP configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the requested (I believe). Expectant. Thanks

Comment: The pointcut looks okay to me, so you probably have a configuration issue. But my expertise is in the area of AspectJ, not Spring. Anyway, according to the [Spring AOP manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), you need to declare the aspect as a bean (commented out in your XML config) and maybe should also do something like `<aop:config><aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="aBean">...</aop:aspect></aop:config>`.